# mailchimp integration on a custom footer

Tags: customization, ajax, api, email, plugin-mailchimp

I want the user to be able to opt-in to a MailChimp newsletter within a custom footer, which one. of our clients has asked for. The client also uses MailChimp so we therefore cannot use anything like contactform-7 etc

The two images below will help explain. The user will type in their email address and will submit the email to subscribe to the newsletter. I repeat this is in a custom footer and I am trying to do this from a child theme

[image: for the firs][image]

I tried following the MailChimp api documentation for adding a member to an existing list https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/list-members/ . This didn't work. It caused the site to crash

I have seen some code here which has been useful since it allows me to pass information from my JS file to my functions.php file https://artisansweb.net/mailchimp-integration-in-wordpress-without-using-a-plugin/

However, I keep receiving the same error when I type in an email that passes the regex
'Something went wrong, please try again'

I have checked the network tab on chrome and the email, a security token and the correct action are all showing - so information is being passed from JS to php. It also (weirdly) is showing a 200 code after submitting. However, there are no new subscribers showing on MailChimp and the error message above is showing (which if you look below is the default case in the subscribe_user_to_mailchimp function)

How can I resolve this?

Code is below:

functions.php

```
// enqueue js for footer (subscribing to newsletter)
  wp_register_script('kingster-script-child-footer', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/footer.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-effects-core'));

  // Localize the script with new data
  $script_array = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'security' => wp_create_nonce("subscribe_user"),
  );
  wp_localize_script( 'kingster-script-child-footer', 'aw', $script_array );

  // Enqueued script with localized data.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'kingster-script-child-footer' );

  add_action('wp_ajax_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user_to_mailchimp');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user_to_mailchimp');
   
  function subscribe_user_to_mailchimp() {
      check_ajax_referer('subscribe_user', 'security');
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $audience_id = '12905';
      $api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us17';
      $data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);
      $url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $audience_id .'/members';
      $auth = base64_encode( 'user:' . $api_key );
      $arr_data = json_encode(array( 
          'email_address' => $email, 
          'status' => 'subscribed' //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
      ));
   
      $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'headers' => array(
                  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                  'Authorization' => "Basic $auth"
              ),
              'body' => $arr_data,
          )
      );
   
      if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
         $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
         echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
      } else {
          $status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
          switch ($status_code) {
              case '200':
                  echo $status_code;
                  break;
              case '400':
                  $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
                  echo $api_response['title'];
                  break;
              default:
                  echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
                  break;
          }
      }
      wp_die();
  }
```

js/footer.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var subscribeButton = $('#subscribe-newsletter-button');
    var subscribeInput = $('#subscribe-newsletter-form-input')
    
    $(subscribeButton).click(function() {
         var email = $(subscribeInput).val()
         if(isEmail(email)) {
            var data = {
                'action': 'subscribe_user',
                'email': email,
                'security': aw.security
            };
      
            $.post(aw.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if (response == 200) {
                    alert('You have subscribed successfully.');
                } else {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('This is not a valid email');
        }
    });
})

function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

edit: I printed the error message and got this in the response:

```
(
    [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [server] => openresty
                    [content-type] => application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
                    [content-length] => 197
                    [x-request-id] => 75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d
                    [link] => <https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/ProblemDetailDocument.json>; rel="describedBy"
                    [content-encoding] => gzip
                    [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                    [date] => Tue, 25 Aug 2020 09:58:36 GMT
                )

        )

    [body] => {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":"75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d"}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 404
            [message] => Not Found
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
    [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
        (
            [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
                (
                    [body] => {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":"75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d"}
                    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: openresty
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 197
X-Request-Id: 75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d
Link: <https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/ProblemDetailDocument.json>; rel="describedBy"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 09:58:36 GMT
Connection: close

{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":"75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d"}
                    [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [server] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => openresty
                                        )

                                    [content-type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
                                        )

                                    [content-length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 197
                                        )

                                    [x-request-id] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 75f70c65-afc6-42f8-806f-2ecb7080071d
                                        )

                                    [link] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => <https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/ProblemDetailDocument.json>; rel="describedBy"
                                        )

                                    [content-encoding] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => gzip
                                        )

                                    [vary] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Accept-Encoding
                                        )

                                    [date] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Tue, 25 Aug 2020 09:58:36 GMT
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [status_code] => 404
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 
                    [redirects] => 0
                    [url] => https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/12905/members
                    [history] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                        (
                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [filename:protected] => 
            [data] => 
            [headers] => 
            [status] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: @Rup thanks for this. I console.logged this: console.log(aw.ajaxurl) which is referring to $script_array['ajaxurl'] and it returned this: http://localhost:8888/lfs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. I'm not sure whether it should refer to this and whether this is the right thing to console.log? What do you think? I'm new to wp and php so appreciate your pointers

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was getting confused between JavaScript and PHP - I meant log out the complete Mailchimp API call response, which is in PHP and which you wouldn't see in your network tab. I'd try either `error_log( print_r( $response, true ) );` which will write the response to the server's error log, or replace your `echo 'Something went wrong.'` with `print_r( $response );` which will return the whole Mailchimp API response from your AJAX API call instead, so you can see the details there.

Comment: @Rup great, that was really helpful! It returned a long message. Not sure how to decipher it and can't copy and paste it since it's too long for the comments. I'll add it to my original post

Comment: @Rup just added it to the original post

Comment: Thanks! "404 Not Found" is the important bit - it looks like your $url is wrong. I don't know what it should be, sorry. It might mean your audience ID is wrong, or you need a list ID not an audience ID? (I don't know the distinction.) Here's the documentation for that API, and it looks like the general format of the URL is correct: https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/list-members/add-member-to-list/

Comment: @Rup thanks for this again! I've taken a look at the documentation but weirdly I can't get the api call to work from WP. It requires composer. I tried installing the mc4wp plugin and using their composer and targetting autoload.php in there but it doesn't seem to work. Will keep looking. Cheers